# I need code for FOREACH loop or for loop for four variables

Tags: c#, foreach

I have four arrays of equal length
I am using those arrays in foreach loops.
I am using four variables(i,j,k,l) to increment and to proceed

I am writing my code inside the four nested loops, that code should execute when i=0,j=0,k=,0,l=0
i=1,j=1,k=1,l=1
i=2,j=2,k=2,l=2
.....(depending on the array length)

Please suggest me the code for this required segment.

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
          foreach (string fieldName in splitFieldnames)
          {
              i = 0;
              foreach (string dataType in splitDatatypeNames)
              {
                  j = 0;
                  foreach (string controlName in SplitControlNames)
                  {
                      k = 0;
                      foreach (string controlType in splitControlTypeNames)
                      {
                          if (i == j && j == k && k == l)
                          {

                              if (controlType == "textbox" && dataType == "string")
                              {

                                  Response.Write("_Student." + fieldName + "= " + controlName + ".Text;");
                                  l++;
                                  break;
                              }

                          }
                          k++;

                      }

                      j++;
                  }



                  i++;

              }

          }
```

Comment: can you at least specify (and tag) what language this is supposed to be?

Comment: tagged C# as that's what it looks like...OP please correct if not.

Comment: are any of the collection indexed i.e. splitDatatypeNames[j]

Comment: I'd say: refactor. Any deep nesting is a big candidate for refactoring. Step 1: put each foreach in its own method. Other than that, I'm afraid I don't understand the question asked.

Comment: this code won't work unless the **very first elements** match. The deepest nested loop only increments the loop control variable on the match condition...

Answer (score 1):

I think using LINQ would save you a lot of manual coding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var splitFieldnames = new string[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" };
    var splitDatatypeNames = new string[] { "datatype1", "string", "string" };
    var SplitControlNames = new string[] { "control1", "control2", "control3" };
    var splitControlTypeNames = new string[] { "combobox", "textbox", "textbox"};

    // this code can handle different sized arrays, but is based strictly
    // on the size of the splitFieldnames array as the base.
    var splitMerged = splitFieldnames.Select
        ((c, idx) =>
            new
            {
                fieldName = c,
                dataType = splitDatatypeNames.Length > idx ? 
                    splitDatatypeNames[idx] : "",
                controlName = SplitControlNames.Length > idx ? 
                    SplitControlNames[idx] : "",
                controlTypeName = splitControlTypeNames.Length > idx?
                    splitControlTypeNames[idx] : "",
            });

   foreach (var item in splitMerged
      .Where(c => c.controlTypeName == "textbox" && c.dataType == "string"))
   {
       Response.Write("_Student." + item.fieldName + "= " 
           + item.controlName + ".Text;");
   }
```

The resulting output would be look like:

```
_Student.field2= control2.Text;
_Student.field3= control3.Text;
```

I *hope* that's what you're looking for, LOL...

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case a DataTable would be better than 4 arrays, and algorithm you require will be trivial with such data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is process the same index in the four arrays, just use one loop and use a counter to access the value in each array in that one loop:

```
foreach(string fieldName in SplitControlNames)
{
    dataType = splitDatatypeNames[arrayPosition];
    controlName = SplitControlNames[arrayPosition];
    controlType  = splitControlTypeNames[arrayPosition];

    if (controlType == "textbox" && dataType == "string")
        Response.Write("_Student." + fieldName + "= " + controlName + ".Text;");

    arrayPosition++;
}
```

Or, create and populate a structure that has four values in it (fieldName, dataType, controlName, controlType) and have one array of that structure

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code is really simple.. If you only need to show the data when i=j=k=l, then no need for any loop, or even for the existence of i,j,k,l.
If you can assure me that all this strings in whatever thing (a collection? an array? a dictionary?) are ordered, is ok. 
If they are ordered, then throw away all the for each, and just access each one by position for all the controls you have in the collection that has the minimun.
If all this collection are not ordered, then this is totally uselles, since it will produce differents results on each run.
I will edit this answers with some code, once you can tell me if this is ordered or not.

EDIT:

First of all, you need to check what collection has the least items (since you can't go beyond that)... I don't know the types of this things (you didn't provide them), so let's assume they have a count property.

```
int minimun = splitFieldnames.count;
if (splitDatatypeNames.count < minimun)
    minimun = splitDatatypeNames.count;
if (SplitControlNames.count < minimun)
    minimun = SplitControlNames.count
if (splitControlTypeNames.count < minimun)
    minimun = splitControlTypeNames.count
```

once you have the minimun value (since you can't go beyond that), just iterate on that and print whatever you want

```
for (int i = 0; i < minimun;i++)
{
    if (splitControlTypeNames[i].tostring() == "textbox" && splitDatatypeNames[i].tostring() == "string")
        {
            //Response.Write("_Student." + fieldName + "= " + controlName + ".Text;");
            //Also, a parametric string would be better ;)
            string result = string.format("_Student.{0}= {1}.Text;",splitFieldnames[0].tostring(),SplitControlNames[0].tostring());
            Response.Write(result);
            l++;
        }
}
```

I don't know the types, so I'm assuming that they have a tostring method an a count property

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` instead of `foreach`

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitFieldnames.Length; i++)
{
    string fieldName = splitFieldnames[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < splitDatatypeNames.Length; j++)
    { 
        string dataType = splitDatatypeNames[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < SplitControlNames.Length; k++)
        { 
            string controlName = SplitControlNames[k];
            for (int l = 0; l < splitControlTypeNames.Length; l++)
            {
                string controlType = splitControlTypeNames[l];
                if (i == j && j == k && k == l)
                { 
                    if (controlType == "textbox" && dataType == "string")
                    { 
                        Response.Write("_Student." + fieldName + "= " + controlName + ".Text;");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that `break` will only break out of the innermost loop! Consider using a `return` statement instead.

---

UPDATE (in response to your edit):

The solution is simple, use only one index variable and only one `for`-loop instead of a lot of `foreach`-loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitFieldnames.Length; i++)
{
    if (splitControlTypeNames[i] == "textbox" && splitDatatypeNames[i] == "string")
    { 
        Response.Write("_Student." + splitFieldnames[i] + "= " + SplitControlNames[i] + ".Text;");
        break;
    }
}
```

(Assuming that you want to stop after the first match. If you want to output all string textboxes, drop the `break` statement.)